# Как редактировать массив который нахоидтся в файле?

Tags: php

Есть файл index.php:

```
<?php include_once 'bets.php'; include_once 'include.php';

    $bet = rand(1, 10000);
    $color = rand(1, 3);
    $bets[] = $userava."*-*".$username."*-*".$bet."*-*".$color;

    for($i = 0; $i <= count($bets); $i++)
        echo $bets[$i]."<br>";

?>
```

Так же файл bets.php:

```
<?php
    $bets=array();
?>
```

При выполнении кода index.php на страницу выводится 1 строка, как и должно. Но как записать эту строку в файл, что бы при следующем обновлении строк стало 2 ?

P.S. В файле будет около 1 000 000 строк, так что перезапись всего файла не подходит. Есть ли решение по добавлению одного элемента в конец массива ?

Comment: Воспользуйтесь готовыми движками базы данных. Или дописывайте в CSV файл.

Comment: Слишком много данных, с файла чтение в разы быстрее чем с бд. А чем csv отличается от других ? И вопрос был как записать, а не в какой файл.

Comment: CSV отличается от приведенного примера тем, что нету "закрывающих" элементов (в вашем случае скобки и закрывающий тег). Поэтому просто дописываем строку и все. Атомарная операция (ну или почти), при которой можно не очень сильно заморачиваться о блокировках. CSV просто для примера привел. В принципе любой файл без сложной структуры, которую нужно менять при каждой записи.

Comment: @tutankhamun Ясно. Это в принципе ясно. Хотел услышать другие варианты, ибо fopen и т.б. мне не по душе. Но раз других вариантов нету - сделаю так. Если хотите можете оформить пост, отмечу как правильный.

Comment: Кроме работы с дескриптором, возвращенным `fopen` можно дописать строку через `file_put_contents($filename, $row, FILE_APPEND);`

Answer (score 1):

Для начала не обязательно ставить закрывающий тег в файле PHP. Он вообще не рекомендуется. Особенно в файлах, которые подключаются в другие скрипты.

Файл для записи можно открывать с флагом `a`. В этом случае указатель будет ставится в конец файла. И в массив можно писать именно так

```
fputs($fp, "\$bets[] = \"" . $value . "\";\n");
```

P.S.: но как уже говорили в комментариях - база данных лучше и быстрей, особенно когда речь идет о миллионах строк.